# NullPointerException on Facebook Native Ads layout with RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception, facebook-ads-api

I'm receiving the following NullPointerException when integrating Facebook Native Ads into my RecyclerAdapter. I have a feeling it has to do with the layout.xml.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
   at com.elgami.feed.FeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FeedRecyclerAdapter.java:128)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCal
```

I've included the two relevant classes and xml layout file in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/santafebound/06380d1d759b048386ca3c0864159295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `Inflater` before your adding `View`.

Comment: @bluemunch wait I have mistake I can fix that.

Comment: Yeah the order doesn't seem to be correct. Inflater should be defined above?

Comment: @bluemunch the error is in this line `  new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);`

Comment: Yeah I'm getting ``java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`` at ``new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);``

Comment: @bluemunch that means you have add this `new_holder.templateContainer.removeViewInLayout(adView);` above to  `new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);`.

Comment: I already do that at line 117:             ``try {
                new_holder.templateContainer.removeViewInLayout(adView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }``

Comment: Thanks. I realized that your solution did in fact solve the NullPointerException. It appears there are more errors in my code unfortunately :(

Comment: @bluemunch it is difficult me to catch because now I am on mobile..

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help. I added another exception if you feel like taking a look. It's so hard to catch bugs with just one set of eyes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170137/illegalstateexception-in-facebook-native-ads-recycler-adapter-integration